# Longbow of Vengeance Upgrade Shadow Strike Kill Online Vendetta

Tags: middle-earth-shadow-of-war

I'm trying to do the final upgrade for the Longbow of Vengeance, which requires me to Shadow Strike Kill an Online Vendetta target. But every time I get them low enough to Shadow Strike Kill the target gets a "last chance" cut-scene and when I kill him it doesn't count as a Shadow Strike Kill.

How am I supposed to finish this upgrade? How can I actually get a lethal Shadow Strike on an Online Vendetta target?

EDIT: Last night I was able to get an insta-kill on a Vendetta target with Shadow Strike but didn't get the credit even though I had the bow equipped.

I was fighting a Vendetta Captain. He didn't have any Terrified By weaknesses or Dazed By weaknesses. However, when you poison a target, they have a few moments wherein they are incapacitated as they vomit and such. I did a Shadow Strike against him while he was vomiting and it did the instant-kill Decapitation Shadow Strike animation, said he was "Decapitated", but then I didn't get the credit on my Vendetta Bow. :(

EDIT 2: I finally found a target that could be Terrified, weakened him, Terrified him, and I did eleven Shadow Strike Kill hits on him... but then he still just did the final animation and I didn't get credit.

How the heck am I supposed to complete this upgrade?

I captured the whole thing this time:

Comment: That does sound annoying.. since you usually only get one last chance (unless you have that one perk enabled that gives you two), I think the only way might be to let them "win" the last chance then shadow strike kill them. They wont get a second chance and it should go through that time. At least I would think it would.

Comment: I'm not talking about MY "Last Chance" (yes, I have the ability that gives me an extra), I'm talking about the CAPTAIN's "Last Chance." I don't know what else to call it. It's when they get a cutscene and make some snarky comment and then I have to hit the button in order to finish the kill. I tried letting him live in order to Shadow Strike him again, but when I let him live it causes him to fully heal. I tried then bringing him back down near 0 and Shadow Striking him again, but he still got the "Last Chance" animation.

Comment: Ahh ok I got you. For some reason, I was thinking online vendetta had you face another player, not a captain.. been a while since I played this one. Hmm.. this is a tricky one then. It almost sounds like a bug with how thats supposed to work. Very weird.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Vendetta gear set is infamously hard to complete challenges for, if you wait too long.

In order to finish an orc off with a Shadow Strike, the attack must deal enough damage to bring them to 0 health. If the attack brings them close to dead, but with a very small amount of health remaining, you will perform the cinematic QTE execution, as you've seen yourself. Due to your level, you're now trying to kill level 80 enemies with a level 40 weapon, which makes it very hard to deal enough damage to bypass the QTE.

My suggestion is then to increase damage dealt with your bow as much as possible. Equip Warrior Gems in your bow, armor, and cloak slots, try to only complete this challenge against orcs with a weakness to ranged weapons; a mortal weakness to ranged weapons would also instantly complete the challenge, but mortal weaknesses are rare at level 80.

From my personal experience, a QTE execution is more likely to get triggered if the fight has been particularly long, so try not to drag the fight out too much. Check how much a Shadow Strike lowers the orc's health bar by, and try to bring the orc's health below that point before you go for the kill. If you're worried about triggering the QTE before even attempting a Shadow Strike, regular arrows will let you deal damage from out of the QTE's range.

Once you find an orc with a weakness to ranged attacks, I'd suggest just letting the QTE fail on purpose if you accidentally trigger it. As long as you keep trying, you will eventually get lucky and kill the orc with a Shadow Strike.

Comment: How can I check the damage numbers on my Shadow Strike and how much health the Orc has left? All I can see is the small partial circle health bar and it's very hard to tell how close they are to dead.

Comment: You can't see an orc's health numerically, you have to judge it based on the health bar.

Comment: Ok, well that is going to be nigh impossible since it looked like he had zero health during the last 6 Shadow Strikes in my video.

Comment: As I said, it is very hard to complete this challenge if you wait too long. Your best chance now is to increase your damage as much as you can, and try to kill an orc with a weakness to ranged attacks.

Answer (score 3):

Hey if you're still struggling with this challenge do NOT use the default shadow strike. My technique was to replenish elf-shot via draining grunts and then pulling the Online Vendetta target using the Shadow Strike pull upgrade once his health is low enough. It may take several arrow replenishments which is why I have it set to give me arrows when I drain grunts... easier than running around the compound looking for inconveniently placed arrows. Once you've restocked keep pulling him to you via the Shadow Strike kill pull. Worked for me. Hope it works for you.